# Is it necessary to have root when executing bin/install during the installation and deployment of Galaxybase?

Tags: graph-databases

Is it necessary to have root when executing bin/install during the installation and deployment of Galaxybase? What if I don't have root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have root, you can execute `bin/install-common` for installation.
However, this way requires manually installing the Docker service and the user must belong to the Docker user group.